# Where to change for external image storage in Opencart?

Tags: amazon-s3, opencart

I am planning to store all my images on S3 Amazon service. Opencart system uses 4 different image sizes. Which one is better for website page load and optimize opencart;  resizing all images and upload to S3 or just uploading main image to S3 and let opencart image cache resize the other picture sizes ?

Thanks

Comment: "Which one is better" questions aren't really on topic here.  Can you rephrase this to avoid asking for opinions?

Comment: Store main image to S3 storage. Opencart resize images on the fly and store as a cache image on website server. Also change the storage path in `config.php` and `admin/config.php`

Comment: // HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www.xxxx.com/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://www.xxxx.com/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/var/www/html/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/var/www/html/system/');
define('DIR_DATABASE', '/var/www/html/system/database/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/var/www/html/catalog/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/var/www/html/catalog/view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/var/www/html/system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/var/www/html/image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/var/www/html/system/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/var/www/html/download/

Comment: where to change for external image url

Answer (score 0):

Upload normal images into s3 storage and give the storage path in config.php , opencart automatically does the resizing while rendering

Comment: How about using CDN instead of S3 image storage. Does it give me better  website load performance ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a cdn plugin it solves the headache for you.

Comment: If I use cdn service from a company, do I really need to call images from external server to improve my website load speed and performance ?

Comment: you dont have to, i meant to se the cdn plugin to connect to s3 you can use any other cdn such as max etc.